# Keep active link (box) highlighted

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using "boxes" (which are actually list elements), which contain an image and a title, for navigation. By hovering over it the box receives a shadow to better highlight the box. Once clicked, I'd like to keep the box highlighted in the same way.

I managed to get a small jQuery script working that way, the CSS only partly. The CSS is somewhat flawed, and I can't see how to make it work correctly. Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/hwffg999/), below the code. The ".active" class is at the bottom of the CSS list.

```
    <div class="explore">
        <div class="explore_body">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li><a href="#!" ><img src="http://geg.informea.org/wp-content/themes/geg/images/air_pollution.png" /></a><a href="#!" class="album_title">Air pollution and air quality</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!" ><img src="http://geg.informea.org/wp-content/themes/geg/images/biodiversity.png"/></a><a href="#!" class="album_title">Biodiversity</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>      
    </div>
```

CSS:
        .explore {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 70%;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

```
    .explore_body {
      width: 100%;
      /* border: 1px solid #f00; */
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      padding-top: 5px;
      clear: both;
      background: #F4F4F4;
      *background: #F4F4F4; /* star hack to target IE6 & 7*/
    }

    .explore_body ul {
      margin: 5px;
      padding-top: 5px;
      clear: both;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .explore_body ul li {
      display: inline-block; /*IE7 doesn't support inline-block */
      zoom: 1;
      *display: inline; /* star hack to target IE6 & 7*/
      /* background: url(images/album.png); */
      width: 130px;
      height: 145px;
      margin: 5px 5px;
    }

    .explore_shadow {
      width: 100%;
      height: 20px;
      /* background: url(images/explore_shadow.png) no-repeat; */
    }

    .explore_body ul li img {
      width: 120px;
      height: 100px;
      margin: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
    }

    .explore_body ul li {
      opacity: 0.9;
      filter:alpha(opacity=90); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }

    .explore_body ul li:hover {
      opacity: 1;
      filter:alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
      -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px #666;
    }       

    .explore_body ul li:selected {
      opacity: 1;
      filter:alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
      -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px #666;
    }       


    .album_title {
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-left: 5px;
      color: #3c72d2;
      font-weight: bold;
      max-width: 140px;
      text-align: left;
      clear: both;
    }

    .album_title:hover {
      color: #1F3D6F;
    }

    .active {
      display: inline-block; /*IE7 doesn't support inline-block */
      zoom: 1;
      *display: inline; /* star hack to target IE6 & 7*/
      /* background: url(images/album.png); */
      width: 130px;
      height: 135px;
      opacity: 1;
      filter:alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
      -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px #666;
    }
```

jQuery:

```
        $(function () {
        $("#nav li a").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#nav li a").addClass("active").not(this).removeClass("active");
        });
    });
```

Thanks for any help in figuring the right CSS out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be targeting the parent element and not the `a` tag, so modify your script like

```
$(function () {
    $("#nav li a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#nav li a").parent().addClass("active").not($(this).parent()).removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hwffg999/1/)

Also, if you see, the box shadow touches the bottom of the text, hence, looks unprofessional, inorder to solve that, assign `padding-bottom: 10px;` to `.explore_body ul li`

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/hwffg999/2/)

Comment: Thanks so much! Great! Yep, the shadow-touching-the-text was only in the fiddle, not in my online-version.

Comment: It seems that the (second) link which I use within that line doesn't work anymore with the above proposed solution. That is: I have in the same line on the screen a jquery-link and an external link  (with an image-tag). The external one doesn't work anymore. [Here is the fiddle.](http://fiddle.jshell.net/luftikus143/Ljh96fo7/2/) Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: @luftikus143 are you looking for something like this? http://fiddle.jshell.net/Ljh96fo7/3/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery looks for the CSS ''before'' the page finishes loading. Use this code as your first line:

```
    $( document ).ready( function() {
```